# Opening files (csv.gz) containing undefined characters and passing files into function

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, unicode, decode

I have a function where the arguments passed are 5 filepaths. However, the first path is to a csv.gz where there seems to be an undefined character inside of the file. How can I work around this?

I'm using Python version 3.11.1. Code and error message shown below.

```py
function(r"filepath1", r"filepath2", r"filepath3", r"filepath4", r"filepath5")
```

Error Message:

```
Cell In[3], line 8, in function(filepath1, filepath2, filepath3, filepath4, filepath5)
 6 file1DateMap = {}
 7 infd = open(file1path1, 'r')
 8 infd.readline()
 9 for line in infd:
10     tokens = line.strip().split(',')
 
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py:23, in IncrementalDecoder.decode(self, input, final)
22 def decode(self, input, final=False):
23     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 94: character maps to undefined
```

I tried

```py
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```

but encoding was undefined in my version of Python.

I tried the "with open" method

```py
file2 = r"file2path"
file3 = r"file3path"
file4 = r"file4path"
file5 = r"file5path"
file1name = r"file1path"
with open(file1name, 'r') as file1:
    function(file1, file2, file3, file4, file5)
```

but the function was expecting a string:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper

I am expecting the function to run and write the processed output to folders on my desktop.

***UPDATE***

I checked the encoding of the file in Visual Studio Code, it stated UTF 8. I wrote the following code:

```py
with open(r"path1", encoding="utf8") as openfile1:
    file1 = openfile1.read()
```

Received this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

***UPDATE 2***

Checked encoding with this code

```py
with open(r"filepath1") as f:
    print(f)
```

> encoding='cp1252'

However now when I pass the new encoding argument:

```py
with open(r"path1", encoding="cp1252") as openfile1:
    file1 = openfile1.read()
```

I am back to square 1 with the following error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 94: character maps to undefined

***UPDATE 3***

Gzip worked. I used the following code:

```py
import gzip
with gzip.open(r"path1", mode="rb") as openfile1:
    file1 = openfile1.read()
```

Comment: *"I tried "encode=utf-8"* Can you edit your post to include the specific code that you tried?

Comment: Edited the post to show the code

Comment: Given the error you received it is safe to say the file is not in UTF-8 format. Why do you think it is encoded as UTF-8? How was the file created? What does `file path1` output? What does `od -tx1 path1 | head` output?

Comment: I checked the format again. Please see response above.

Comment: Hi. You mention a GZ (gzip) file. Does your code decompress/inflate the zip file before trying to read it as text-CSV?

Comment: In Update 2, Python isn't telling you that cp1252 is the **correct** encoding for the file. It's telling you that cp1252 is the encoding that it opened the file with (presumably it's the default in your environment).

Comment: (If it's a .gz file, there probably is no "correct" encoding per se. It's a binary file that needs to be decompressed, then the decompressed files can be interpreted as text using the correct encoding. But you can use `gzip.open`, with an encoding specified, to have Python do a lot of this work behind the scenes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open).

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helped. Please see response above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a CSV file compressed into a gzip file, you should be able to read the gzip file as simply as:

```py
with gzip.open("input.csv.gz", "rt", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

I believe you'll want `rt` to read it as text (and not `rb` which will return non-decoded bytes); and of course pick the actual encoding of the file (I always use utf-8 for my examples).

To further decode the CSV in the text file `f`, I recommend using the standard library's csv module:

```py
...
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several bits of confusion present in this source code.

```
with open(file1name, 'r') as file1:
    function(file1, file2, file3, file4, file5)
```

Please understand that `file1` is an open file handle,
with a `type(...)` of TextIOWrapper.
It is iterable, you can request lines of text from it.
In contrast `file2` et al. are `str` pathnames;
you cannot request lines of filesystem text from those objects.

The parallel structure of naming you chose for them
is likely to confuse yourself plus any hapless maintenance
engineer who encounters this code in the coming months.
Recommend you adopt names like `path2` .. `path5`.

---

Your default encoding appears to be
[CodePage1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).
You requested that encoding with `open(file1name, 'r')`
by leaving out the optional `encoding=` parameter.
Note that `mode='r'` is the default,
so you could have left that one out, as well.

In contrast, `open(filename, encoding="utf8")`
opened for read access using quite a different encoding.

The encoding is a property of the underlying .CSV file,
and not of your program.
That is, you **must** know what the correct underlying encoding is,
and you **must** tell `open` the correct encoding.
You can do that by default or you can do it explicitly,
as long as you get it right.
I recommend doing it explicitly.

If you don't know the encoding,
use `/usr/bin/file`, `/usr/local/bin/iconv`,
or a text editor to learn what it is,
and perhaps to change it to UTF-8
if you're unhappy with its current encoding.

Most files on most modern machines
should be UTF-8 encoded -- to do otherwise
is to invite trouble. But I digress.

Once you've settled on some known encoding,
pass it in to `open` via the `encoding=`
parameter and you're in business!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the post please see above.